# 'Team's interaction' or 'team interaction'?

Tags: grammaticality, possessives, apostrophe

I'm not sure which one is correct here:

> It has influenced our (team/team's) interaction and coordination skills.

Is it team's since the interaction is possessive? Or team?

Answer (score 0):

Our *team interaction* suggests the kind of interaction skills and doesn't specify whose skills other than *ours*. It should really be hyphenated [team-interaction]

Our *team's interaction* suggests interaction within our specific team.

I suspect, in your context, it should be:

> *"It has influenced our team's interaction and coordination skills"*

Comment: Is interaction different from coordination?